# Angular8 Library: 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: angular8, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am new at building Angular Library. I have created an angular library successfully from CLI. However, I wanted to add a new service(class) in the library. And while I want to build the library, its always throwing the error as in the screenshot:
 [Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUtYi.png)

I have checked some discussions on the web but none of them resolve my problem.

The library structure as in the screenshot:

[Library structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYpoh.png)

I have created separated the folders of classes, services, and components.

The newly created component from CLI is working fine, only for the services and classes, the error is throwing while building.

I can provide more info if required.

thanks,

Comment: you need to have your service in library directory in order to use it

Comment: hi, thank you. yes, It is inside the library directory. like this: src/lib/services/abcService, if you notice in the screenshot, at the bottom, I have created services folder where I am planing to put other services

Comment: @NikolaStekovic I have updated my comment